# Finding the compression type in an image file

Tags: java, compression, tiff, bin, javax.imageio

I want to find the compression type for an image that is currently stored as .bin file (dont know why its stored like this it just is) but my question is should I find the compression type while its in a .bin file or should I do it when I convert to a .tiff file. I done tons of research and not sure whats the best way. If anyone can give me some feedback that will be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the format. Data means nothing without a schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the first few bytes of the file to get at least a hint as to what the image format is.  Most file formats start with a few "magic numbers", precisely so that the format can be verified by the decoder.  You can use this [good list of magic numbers](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) for guessing what you have, and then trying the appropriate image decoder on the data.